# Stretch Image to fit Image View using Glide

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-glide

I want to make an image fit into my `image view`. I am loading the image programmatically using Glide. It does load the image but does not stretch it to fit my entire `image view`. It leaves blank spaces on both sides like this

[image]

I want to display my entire image without cropping so I can't use

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

There's a way to fit the entire image into my `image view` by using

```
android:background="@drawable/image"
```

It stretches my image to fit the entire `image view`. But how can I achieve the same if i am loading the image using Glide ?

Comment: you are give image view height and width wrap_cotent

Comment: I can but i want my image width to be fit the entire screen and height to be 250dp.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally got the answer to it.
Simply use

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

in the xml ImageView tag like this and load image using Glide or BitmapFactory without using any scaleType attribute there.

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/image_view"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Load Image to the image View

```
Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view));
```

Comment: This will scale the image and can't be used if the aspect ratio of image is not known.

Answer (score 2):

You can use centerCrop method.

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.default_image).into(img);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your images to fit width and have a dynamic height, without cropping the content, for ex: Like instagram feed, set the height to wrap content, width to match parent and set adjustViewBounds to true.

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which **show your full image in center**.

```
imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```